# ARP message how to get IP

Tags: c, linux, arp

I need to know the IP adress of the sender of the ARP reply.I tried using recvfrom but I can't get the IP address from it.Thank you for the help.

I have some child processes that each send a ARP requst to an IP  adress.The problem is that the response comes to all the children because the socket is raw so I need somehow to know for what child the response arrived.I tried

```
struct sockaddr_ll linkLayerAddr;
char buf[32];
int sockaddr_len=sizeof(linkLayerAddr);
memset(&linkLayerAddr,0,sizeof(linkLayerAddr));
fcntl(sock,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK);
nanosleep(&time1,NULL);

if(recvfrom(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0,(struct sockaddr*)&linkLayerAddr,&sockaddr_len)==-1){

info.status=0; 
}//se primeste raspunsul
else{
info.status=1;

}
```

I wait 800000 nanosecond for a reply and I want to know for what IP the message came.With recvfrom i can only get the MAC adress.

Comment: provide some code of what you tested. 
Be precise, do you intend to get the IP from the packet structure, or from the payload itself?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think it's possible, since ARP packets encode the requestor and the response only. You could cache an ARP table yourself (or probe the system ARP table) and look up the MAC adddress of the source of the response packet (in the ethernet header, not the ARP payload) though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [linux ARP recvfrom information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253639/linux-arp-recvfrom-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emile, i have already replied to the same question.

Click here:

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253639/linux-arp-recvfrom-information/14256039#14256039)

if you don't like the answer, let's discuss it, but avoid opening new question with the same identical topic

Comment: Thank you for the answers.I don't understand how I can dissect an Arp package.Should I acces the ARP cache with ip neighbour ?

Comment: @Emil Grigore No, it's the bytes in the packet you received.